# Read binary data of video files & Open it from Google Drive

Tags: python, video, google-drive-api, bytestream, python-vlc

I tried to read a video store on Google Drive by get the file data content following the code block below, i don't want to download the file to local, just read & load directly from GD.,

```
...
def print_file_content(service, file_id):
  """Print a file's content.

  Args:
    service: Drive API service instance.
    file_id: ID of the file.

  Returns:
    File's content if successful, None otherwise.
  """
  try:
    # GET FILE'S DATA AND READ
    content = service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id).execute()
    < CODE - OPEN CONTENT/VIDEO >
    #
  except Exception as e:
    print('An error occurred: %s' % e)
print_file_content(service, file_id)
```

i got file's data, It has this format:

```
b'\x1aE\xdf\xa3\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00#B\x86\x81\x01B\xf7\x81\x01B\xf2\x81\x04B\xf3\x81\x08B\x82\x88matroskaB\x87\x81\x04B\x85\x81\x02\x18S\x80g\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00A\xffE\x11M\x9bt\xbeM\xbb\x8cS\xab\x84f\xa9I\x15S\xac\x82\x00\xdfM\xbb\x8cS\xab\x84k\xaeT\x16S\xac\x82\x01\'M\xbb\x8cS\xab\x84g\xc3T\x12S\xac\x82\x01\xafM...'
```

then tried to **read** `content` by the mean of using: **`binascii, open(content,'rb'), io.BytesIO`** but all is not working, error.

i found a way to **open** video file is [`vlc`](https://pypi.org/project/python-vlc/), but when apply `data read` to it by all of above ways, even just paste `content` itself, it still not working.

**`HOW TO READ & OPEN A VIDEO FROM BINARY BYTES DATA OF IT BUT NOT A VIDEO OBJECT?`**